# How to transfer input from python to excel in increasing row each time the code is run

Tags: python

I am a beginner in python and kindly have a question.
My intention for this code is for it to accept input in Python and transfer them into Excel in the manner of increasing rows.
For instance, the 1st input goes to A1, and the next input for the next run goes to A2, and etc.

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('name.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

yourname=input("Please enter your name here: ")
i=0
while True:
    ws['A'+i] = yourname
    i += 1
    break
wb.save('name.xlsx')
```

Thank you.

Comment: This should help you start: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-excel-tutorial on a side note - try looking into vb.Net it's way better technology for your purpose...

Comment: Read [write-a-workbook](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#write-a-workbook)

Answer (score 1):

**ws['A'+i] = yourname** this might not work with openpyxl ,you can use this with xlwings and for openpyxl use this one **ws.cell(rownum, colnum).value=data**

```
import openpyxl as op
wb = op.load_workbook('name.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

i=1
# i = 1 because Excel row starts with 1 
while True:
    # enter exit when you're done
    yourname = input("Please enter your name here: ")
    if yourname == 'exit':
        break

    else:
        # i is for row count and 1 is for column column, you can change these as per your need

        ws.cell(i,1).value= yourname
        i= i+1

wb.save('name.xlsx')
```